`psql` no language specified for files and redirections, but not for code pasted manually
I have the following problem:
I have super simple SQL code from a tutorial, saved into a file test.sql.
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE SQL
    AS 'select $1 + $2;'
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    COST 100;

This code works fine when I am pasting it into the psql console manually,
starting psql as:
PGPASSWORD=... psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres -S postgres

However, when passing this file as input to the command via a redirection fails:
PGPASSWORD=... psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres -S postgres < test.sql
psql:test.sql:1: ERROR:  no language specified

This also fails:
PGPASSWORD=... psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -U postgres -S postgres -f test.sql
psql:test.sql:1: ERROR:  no language specified

What is going on?

Your example is working without any problems in my environment. Are you sure so file test.sql has correct content?

Works here. What OS and version?

The issue lies in the LANGUAGE SQL declaration in your function definition, it's working fine - please check :
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION add(integer, integer) RETURNS integer
    LANGUAGE 'sql'
    AS 'select $1 + $2;'
    RETURNS NULL ON NULL INPUT
    COST 100;


The SQL in the question resulted in this: https://i.sstatic.net/7Dpil0eK.png, so please add some explaining on why this should solve which(?) problem.
